# Ext. news: get news id in controller

Tags: typo3, extbase, tx-news

I want to place a new plugin (from own extension) on the news detail page, which shows me news from related categories.

My problem is: How to get the news id in my new plugin controller.

```
$arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
```

does not work.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GeneralUtility::_GET for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use below TYPO3 `GeneralUtility::_GP()` function for get another extension arguments in your own extension Controller file. Like below

```
$newsArr = GeneralUtility::_GP('tx_news_pi1');
$this->newsUid = intval($newsArr['news']);
```